# This is simple crawl with more than one site but it fails

Tags: php, arrays, curl

I am a n00b so please bear with these dumb questions - I know my curl commands work I can do it one at a time but when I add this array and counter it just not work. 
I know this is basics but I have tried looking for stuff and this looks like it should work. of course I am wrong HELP,

```
<?php
$proxy = '127.0.0.1:8118';
$proxy = explode(':', $proxy);
$site[] = "http://site1.com";
$site[] = "http://site2.com";
$site[] = "http://site3.com";
$site[] = "http://site4.com";
// $site[] = explode(':', $site[]);
$maxsites = count($site);

// echo $site[];
echo $maxsites;

$counter ='1';

echo $counter;
echo "site count ".$site[$counter];

while  (  $counter <= 4);
{
echo "got to here";
    $url = $site[$counter];
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site[$counter]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_HTTP);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy[0]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy[1]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    $exec = curl_exec($ch);
    echo curl_error($ch);
    print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
    echo $exec;
    $counter++;
}
?>
```

Comment: You've defined the value of `$counter` as a string, yet are referring to it as an integer in your condition check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you could provide An error or two would be super awesome, but at first glance this issue might be messing you up:

```
while  (  $counter <= 4);
{
```

should be

```
while($counter <= 4)
{
```

theres no need for that semicolon

also you set `$counter` equal to the character 1, not the integer it should be:

```
$counter = 1;
```

Comment: no problem, if this helped you, check it so with the checkmark under the vote counter.